# How to replace only zeroes with some conditions on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, mean

I have searched many places but still can't come up neither with my own logic neither find on the internet ...

**problem**
I have students performance dataset while performing EDA , i came up with a small problem

like ,why students having zero 'absences' have zeroes in their final grades ..
that is practically impossible for a student to be present the whole year and still get a zero in their finals

So I decided to filter out all the rows with zeroes in those two columns using

```
dataset[(dataset['G3']==0)&(dataset['absences']==0)]
```

but this returned a dataframe
So i tried

```
dataset.loc[(dataset['G3']==0)&(dataset['absences']==0),['G3','absences']]
```

which returned me two columns with the condition satisfied , what i wanted is to replace 'G3' column **zeroes** and 'absences' column **zeroes** to be replaced with their respective means and **not disturb the dataframe too**

i tried to replace them by

```
dataset.loc[(dataset['G3']==0)&(dataset['absences']==0),['G3','absences']].replace(0,np.mean[dataset[['G3','absences']]])
```

[image: i got this series of Zero containing columns]

which threw me error

```
function object cannot be subscriptable
```

I don't know what to do

I have tried many things but still can't get through this problem any solution may help

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to replace with the mean of subset of values != 0, the you can use

```
dataset = pd.DataFrame({'G3': np.random.randint(0,3,100), 
                         'absences' : np.random.randint(0,3,100)})

dataset.loc[(dataset['G3']==0)&(dataset['absences']==0),['G3', 'absences']] = [dataset.loc[(dataset['G3']!=0)]['G3'].mean(), dataset.loc[(dataset['absences']!=0)]['absences'].mean()]
```

Comment: just had a doubt that after Equals to sign why have you started a list then gave all conditions

Comment: thanks for the answer though but it will be nice if you can explain the above comment

Comment: Since we have two values i.e, mean of `G3` and mean of `absences`  we put them in a list. Also the LHS expects two values `['G3', 'absences']`

Comment: So sorry to disturb you again but do help me with this ......like I understood this much ```dataset.loc[(dataset['absences']!=0)]``` but why have you used ```['absences']``` after this cant we do ```dataset.loc[(dataset['absences']!=0)].mean()```

Comment: like how can you use ```[absences]``` after ```loc``` and what does that mean

Comment: I am using `dataset.loc[(dataset['G3']!=0)].mean()` because for `G3` you want to impute with the mean of `G3` and similarly for `absences` you want to impute with mean of `absences`. `dataset['absences']!=0)].mean()` will restrun mean of two columns of `dataset` which are `G3` and `absences`. But yo want only `absences` so I am explicitly getting the `absences` using `dataset.loc[(dataset['absences']!=0)]['absences'].mean()`

Comment: ohk now I get it!!